# tag confusion with [ghost]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

It's not clear if the [ghost](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ghost) tag refers to the blogging software or Symantec's ghost. I suggest that adding two tags might resolve this problem:

• ghost-blog
• ghost-symantec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the majority of the existing questions with the  [ghost](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ghost) tag appear to be about the [Symantec disk cloning and backup software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_(software)), I have only created a single **new [ghost-blog](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ghost-blog) tag** for the newcomer [Ghost blog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_(blogging_platform)).